# ALTER TABLE ate all the free disk space and is in progress

Tags: mysql, debian

I changed the dimension of a field in a 6Gb table. As a result, all the disk space is over, the process is not finished. What can you recommend me?

```
df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda              24G   22G     0 100% /
tmpfs                 998M     0  998M   0% /lib/init/rw
udev                   10M  112K  9.9M   2% /dev
tmpfs                 998M     0  998M   0% /dev/shm


top - 12:58:38 up 28 days,  6:27,  1 user,  load average: 0.05, 0.06, 0.06
Tasks: 114 total,   2 running, 112 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  1.8%us,  0.7%sy,  0.0%ni, 97.5%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   2042528k total,  1645508k used,   397020k free,    62012k buffers
Swap:   524284k total,    54236k used,   470048k free,  1041392k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND           
 7854 www-data  20   0  231m  13m 7676 S    1  0.7   0:00.08 apache2            
 7755 www-data  20   0  230m  14m 9068 S    1  0.7   0:01.37 apache2            
 7815 www-data  20   0  230m  14m 7884 S    1  0.7   0:00.35 apache2            
 2192 mysql     20   0  720m 180m  532 S    0  9.0 533:53.48 mysqld
```

Comment: Buy a bigger hard drive.

Comment: In the future, certainly, but what to do now to avoid damaging the table?

Comment: First, I'd suggest  making a backup of the whole disk in it's current state. Then, force a reboot, and see what the damage is. You may just be able to drop the column, which may recover the table :/ ... If you have to recover the table, take a look here - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html